# what is the purpose of the asterisk symbol in "complex(*(1,2))" in python without which it will return an error?

Tags: python, math, tuples, operator-keyword

I am learning about complex function in python.

I understand the input to the complex function complex(a, b) and will return a+ bi.
What I don't understand is when I input in tuples form, complex((a, b)), it will return an error but if I use complex(*(a, b)) it will return a+ bi. so in this case, is the asterisk particularly part of complex function's argument when giving it as a tuple or is it performing some kind of operation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*`-operator is used for [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments).

You're not calling the function in the same way. Think of it this way:

```
complex(real=a, imaginary=b)
# vs.
complex(real=(a, b))
```

This is also why you see people write `def fn(*args, **kwargs)`, it means that all arguments and keyword arguments will be unpacked.

Answer (score 0):

Function complex(a,b) needs two parameters in this case. When you run this function like complex((a,b)) you are only giving the function one parameter - which is a tuple with two elements. Asterisk used like this unpacks the iterable- tuple